# Generate regular expression to get iOS device version, device name and UDID

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to write a regular expression to get device name, iOS version and UDID but can't figure out. I have a below list as sample from command line result. So I want to extract only value from below list and ignore all other expression: iPhone Name, 11.3, 606961e11c88934edf3d0956cf5b252a76547129

```
KnownDevices:
   local [86F109DE-9E65-5D16-8A85-CBCESECD6374]
    iPhone Name (11.3) [606961e11c88934edf3d0956cf5b252a76547129]
    Apple TV 1080p (10.2) [1B9FH00C-721C-4740-B22F-7049D4E51AC5] (Simulator)
    iPad (5th generation) (10.3.1) [F1FJA8D1-C966-40BF-B51D-201443E95E0A] (Simulator)
    iPad (5th generation) (11.1) [30B4BEE3-103B-4B58-9C1B-661435D6BA28] (Simulator)
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: I dpn't know much of regular expression but I just tried ^((?!Simulator).)*$ to get rid of Simulator

Answer (score 0):

**Regex**: `(?<Name>.+)(?:\s\((?<Version>[^\)]+)\))\s\[(?<UDID>[^\]]+)\]`

**Details**:

- `(?<>)` Named Capture Group
- `(?:)` Non-capturing group
- `[^]` Match a single character **not** present in the list
- `+` Matches between one and unlimited times
- `\s` matches whitespace character

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dSyTgf/2)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: However, this do not matches when run through command line --> instruments -s devices | grep '(?<Name>.+)(?:\s\((?<Version>[^\)]+)\))\s?\[(?<UDID>[^\]]+)\]'

Comment: @sjgmamer Try this `(.+)(?:\s\(([^\)]+)\))\s\[([^\]]+)\]`